# How to make this 3 Column Design Responsive?

Tags: css, layout, responsive, css-multicolumn-layout

I want to use "The Perfect 3 Column Liquid Layout (Percentage widths)" from this website: https://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm , and make it mobile responsive, but so far I have been unable to do it.

I have added the following code to my .css file, and it does not work.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 629px) { 
    .colmask, 
    .colmid, 
    .colleft {
        float: none ;
        width: 100% ;
    }
}
```

These are the relevant parts of my .css. file.

```
/* column container */

.colmask {
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;         
    overflow:hidden;
}

/* common column settings */

.colright,
.colmid,
.colleft {
    float:left;
    width:100%;         
    position:relative;
}

.col1,
.col2,
.col3 {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 0 1em 0;      

    overflow:hidden;
}

/* 3 Column settings */

.threecol {
    background:#cedcec;     
}

.threecol .colmid {
    right:20%;          
    background:#eaedf4;     
}

.threecol .colleft {
    right:60%;          
    background:#cedcec;     
}

.threecol .col1 {
    width:60%;          
    left:100%;          
}

.threecol .col2 {
    width:20%;          
    left:20%;           
}

.threecol .col3 {
    width:20%;          
    left:80%;           

}
```

Comment: Hello Mateo, I'm sorry but your question is too broad. What do you mean by responsive (somethiong off-screen, none floated, etc...)? What is not working ? What is the html structure of your page ?

Comment: Hi, what I want is that the three columns are reorganized vertically on top of each other when looking at the page from a small mobile phone screen. From a desktop, they of course appear horizontally side by side occupying the whole screen.   That is why I tried to use this code: 

    @media only screen and (max-width: 629px) { 
        .colmask, 
        .colmid, 
        .colleft {
            float: none ;
            width: 100% ;
        }
    }

but it did not work. So I guess I got the code wrong or used the wrong parameters.

Comment: Here is the HTML structure of my page:
[code]
    <div class="colmask threecol">
     <div class="colmid">
      <div class="colleft">
       <div class="col1">
        Center
       </div>
       <div class="col2">
        Left
       </div>
       <div class="col3">
        Right
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

Comment: Wow, I've just read the whole code. Do you need to be able to support IE 5 ? Because that's and old way to solve this layout. The site your refer to is 10 years old. It would be way more simple with more modern technics.

Comment: IE 5? No, I don't think so. Does anybody still use IE 5 anyway?
I thought that by adding the correct "media only screen and (max-width: 629px)..." code to the .css file it would work, but if you tell me there are more modern technics then...

Comment: You've got some `right: xx` and `left: xx`. I wouldn't say that it's a mess, but it won't do any good to you. I would search for **holy grail flexbox** if I were you.